# Kubernetes vs Machine Instance Groups

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

The goal is to make compute engine feel as much like a serverless architecture as possible.

In my system I'm rendering 60 frames per job, each job requires one CPU/process that takes 20s to complete.

Currently my VM is `n1-standard-16` with `1 x NVIDIA Tesla T4`. This means about 16 jobs can be ran in parallel per instance taking around 20s per process (most likely less than 16 if I were to do benchmarking)

My goal is to make it easy to boot up as many instances as needed given a dynamic workload. For example, we want to issue 100 jobs (each responsible for 60 frames and will take roughly 20s to complete)

100 (jobs) / 16 (vCPUs) = 6.25 (instances -- lets round to 7).

Im still learning MIGs, but I dont see a way to manage them this way, its based on CPU usage. My question is would it be better to look into k8s for this need, or is there a way to do this inside a MIG?

Sounds like I can use KEDA, am I understanding it correctly?

sqs-trigger-example.yml

```
apiVersion: keda.sh/v1alpha1
kind: TriggerAuthentication
metadata:
  name: keda-trigger-auth-aws-credentials
  namespace: keda-test
spec:
  podIdentity:
    provider: aws-kiam # or aws-eks when using IRSA
---
apiVersion: keda.sh/v1alpha1
kind: ScaledObject
metadata:
  name: aws-sqs-queue-scaledobject
  namespace: keda-test
spec:
  scaleTargetRef:
    name: hello-world
  triggers:
  - type: aws-sqs-queue
    authenticationRef:
      name: keda-trigger-auth-aws-credentials
    metadata:
      queueURL: myQueue
      queueLength: "1000"
      awsRegion: "eu-west-1"
```

deolpyment-example.yaml

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: load-balancer-example
  name: hello-world
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app.kubernetes.io/name: load-balancer-example
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app.kubernetes.io/name: load-balancer-example
    spec:
      containers:
        - image: nvidia/cuda/ubuntu image here
          name: test
          ports:
            - containerPort: 3000
          resources:
            limits:
              nvidia.com/gpu: 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes. There are multiple ways. One that I can think of is using a pod for each job. Each pod has the resources that your job requires and the pods can be distributed among different Kubernetes nodes that have your hardware requirements.

Now the typical way of autoscaling is using CPU and memory, but you can also autoscale based on specific metrics.  For that I would recommend taking a look [KEDA](https://keda.sh/) to autoscale your jobs based on some specific metric (i.e number of jobs waiting in a queue). KEDA also has the [ScaledJob](https://keda.sh/docs/2.7/concepts/scaling-jobs/) resource that you can use in your case.

P.S. Maybe have other ways of scaling other than CPU, you may want to check with the Google App Engine support.

Comment: Gotcha, I need to investigate how to use MIGs. In terms of using pods that sounds promising, again need to do more research. The reason for asking is to get all the information I can get to make a good investment in terms of learning.

Comment: Sounds good! I hope it all works out! Happy to answer any questions.

Comment: I did some research on Kubernetes. It seems I can use https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/cluster-architecture and create a custom image that I can use within the configuration. Then build 16 containers per pod. I will use KEDA to determine how many pods to create based on workload from I.e dynamo db. Does that sound somewhat right?

Comment: Yes, that sounds like a plan.  You have to make sure that you have query in dynamo that triggers the scaler: https://keda.sh/docs/2.7/scalers/aws-dynamodb/

Comment: Is it possible to trigger via http? Im looking for ways to boot up nodes but cant find anything.

Comment: you can push to a queue through http and then trigger from there? for example: https://keda.sh/docs/2.7/scalers/aws-sqs/

Comment: I updated the OP. I think I understand it correctly. I can create a Deployment which manages my `Pods` and does some load balancing. Then I can connect the KEDA triggers by using the same namespace `hello-world` inside `scaleTargetRef `. It will read SQS or Dynamo whatever, then generate a `Node` per item?

Comment: This seems promising https://github.com/openfaas/faas-netes

Comment: Not a Node, but it will scale pods up and down.  Yeah openfaas is another good one you can try.

Comment: That makes sense. The issue I am facing is each Pod gets assigned a GPU, in a replica set for example, if I have 4 replicas trying to access GPU only one will be granted, the remaining will be stuck in pending. So my options are to wrap my head around this https://blog.ml6.eu/a-guide-to-gpu-sharing-on-top-of-kubernetes-6097935ababf or to fan out nodes within the cluster creating 1 Pod per Node. Im stuck understanding how to make this work.